# Taylor series method for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Hi Guys given the following question

$$y'(x) = \ln(x+y), x_0 = 1, y_0=1$$

Therefore using the taylor series method

$$y = y_0 + (x-x_0)y'_0+\frac{(x^2-2x+1)(y''_0)}{2}+\frac{x^3-3x^2+3x-1}{6}(y'''_0)$$

Therefore

$$y'(x) = \ln(x+y) = \ln x+\ln y$$

$$y''(x) = \frac{d}{dx}ln(x+y)$$

$$\frac{df}{dx} = y = ln(u), u = x+y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x+y}$$

$$\frac{df}{dy} = \frac{y'}{x+y}$$

hence the we get the following

$$y''(x) = \frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+y}y'$$

$$y''(x) = \frac{1+y'}{x+y}$$

$$y'''(x)= \frac{1+y'}{x+y}$$

$$let u = 1+y', v = x+y$$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = y'', \frac{dv}{dx} = 1+y'$$

Placing into the formula

$$\frac{y''(x+y)-(1+y')(1+y')}{(x+y)^2}$$

Comment: You used chain rule then with $u=x+y$ you have :$$y''=\dfrac {d \ln u}{du}\dfrac {du}{dx}=\frac 1 u u'$$ and $u'=1+y'$

Comment: i differentiated the function with respect to x first and then y and added the both terms and got the result. is that not a valid solution? @Aryadeva.

Comment: You can't do that Amir...Even you end with the right answer. Use Chain rule it's better.

Comment: yes i looked at it in terms of doing  a third derivative will i just need to use quotient rule letting u = the numerator and v = denominator @Aryadeva

Comment: Yes you need quotient rule for third derivative

Comment: i will attempt it and repost to make sure i am doing the derivatives correctly would it be possible for you to provide a solution to the third derivative for me to verify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106810/discussion-between-amir-and-aryadeva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'(x) = \ln(x+y), x_0 = 1, y_0=1$$
The second derivative of y is:
$$y''=\dfrac {1+y'}{x+y}$$
$$y''=\dfrac {1+\ln |x+y|}{x+y}$$
You can't write:
$$\ln (x+y)=\ln (x)+\ln(y)$$
Don't confuse with:
$$\ln (xy)=\ln (x)+\ln(y)$$

---

You need to differentiate a log function so: 
$$(\ln (x+y))'=\frac 1{x+y}(x+y)'$$
And $(x+y)'=1+y'$.
Or for any function $f(x)$:
$$(\ln (f(x)))'=\frac 1{f(x)}(f(x))'$$

---

If you prefer substitution and chain rule : $u=x+y$ you have :
$$y'= \ln u $$
$$y''=\dfrac {d \ln u}{du}\dfrac {du}{dx}=\frac 1 u u'$$ and $u'=1+y'$
$$y''=\dfrac {1+y'}{x+y}$$
$$y''=\dfrac {1+\ln (x+y)}{x+y}$$
Use quotient rule for the third derivative:
$$y^{(3)}=-\dfrac {y'(1+y')}{(x+y)^2}$$
$$y^{(3)}=-\dfrac {(1+\ln (x+y))\ln (x+y)}{(x+y)^2}$$

Comment: can you show a breakdown of the steps cause my reattempt at this question

Comment: i reattempted the solution for the second derivative and i got it oh thank you for clearing it up @ Aryadeva. Now i will work out the third derivative and add it to the post.

Comment: i am putting in my solution for the third derivative @ Aryadeva

Comment: i think in my solution i have made a mistake as its not in alignment with your solution @Aryadeva

Comment: Amir your solution is correct. Now substitute the expression for $y''$ we find before @Amir The expression will be simpler then.

Comment: Oh ok @ Aryadeva will do and update as needed thank you for the assistance with the question i very much appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @Aryadeva can you assist me with a integration question i am trying to figure out ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688564/integration-by-parts-for-evaluating-a-differential-equation

Comment: Hi @John Yes sure I posted an answer.

Comment: Hi @Arydeva can you assist with this question in anyway ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702607/central-difference-approximations

Comment: I am unfortunately not really good at numerical methods @john

Comment: oh ok @Aryadeva thanks for responding I hope your good and all is well with you have a great day!