# Integration by parts for evaluating a differential equation

Tags: indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

Hi I am trying to evaluate a integral and I am hoping for some assistance

$$\int \frac{9x^2}{(x^6+9)} dx $$

I have rewritten the problem as shown below

$$\int 9x^2(x^6+9)^{-1}dx$$

Therefore I attempted the question by using integration by parts

$$\int udv = uv- \int vdu$$

$$u = (x^6+9)^{-1}$$
$$du = -6x^5(x^6+9)^{-2} dx$$

$$dv = 9x^2dx$$
$$v = 3x^3$$

Therefore substituting into the integration by parts formula we get

$$\int 9x^2(x^6+9)^{-1} dx = 3x^3(x^6+1)^{-1} - \int -18x^8(x^6+9)^{-2} dx$$

$$\int 9x^2(x^6+9)^{-1} dx = 3x^3(x^6+1)^{-1} - \int 3x^3 \frac{-6x^5}{(x^6+9)^2}dx$$

Then i tried using integration by substitution here

$$let u = x^6+9$$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 6x^5$$

$$\frac{du}{6x^5} = dx$$

$$\int 9x^2(x^6+1)^{-1} dx = 3x^3(x^6+1)^{-1} - \int \frac{-3x^3}{u^2}du$$

This is where i have reached in terms of evaluating the problem When making the substitution I have gotten a $3x^3$ within the integral I am hoping someone can help evaluate this integral.

Now i am working on Picards Method of successive approximations

$$y_0 = y_0 \int f(x,y_0) dx$$

the ODE given was 
$$y' = \frac{x^2}{y^2+1}$$

$$x_0 = 0, y_0 =0$$

Therefore first approximation given by the following

$$y_1 = y_0 + \int f(x,y_0)dx$$

therefore y1

$$y_1 = 0 + \int \frac{x^2}{0+1} dx$$

$$y_1 = \frac{x^3}{3}$$

Second approximation

$$y_2 = y_0 + \int f(x,y_1)dx$$

Therefore we get the following

$$y_2 = 0 + \int \frac{x^2}{\frac{x^6}{9}+1} dx$$

and this is why i am trying to evalaute the integral but the solution which i am seeing is in the form

$$y = \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{-x^9}{81}$$

and i am trying to see how they arrvied at this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{9x^2}{(x^6+9)} dx$$
$$I=\int \frac{3dx^3}{(x^3)^2+9} =\int \frac{dx^3/3}{(x^3/3)^2+1} $$
$$I=\int \frac{du}{u^2+1} $$
Where $u=\dfrac {x^3}3$. Then use the $\arctan  $ function.
$$I=\arctan u +C=\arctan \left(\dfrac {x^3}3 \right)+C $$

Comment: if u look lower down in the comments i came across a solution to this question which is of the form $$y = \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{-x^9}{81}$$ so the solution which i am seeing has me confused

Comment: Oh I see why you're confused. But use  a substitution and then use the arctan function thats all you need @John

Comment: i updated the information in the question i was expecting the solution to be in the form of a series as shown but using the arctan function i am a bit confused @Aryadeva as the  solution required is a form as shown above.

Comment: The solution is just arctan . I don"t see how they get the answer you posted. @John

Comment: yeah thats what is confusing me as well thanks for the solution to the question i  appreciate all of the answers guys!

Comment: You're welcome @John

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Put $$x^3=3t$$

then

$$x^2dx=dt$$

and

$$x^6+9=9(1+t^2)$$

the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\arctan(t)+C$$
$$=\arctan(\frac{x^3}{3})+C$$

Comment: ok that makes sense the integral which i am evaluating is based on a a solution for an ODE where i am using picards method where the $$y' = \frac{x^2}{y^2+1}$$ so when evaluating the first approximation i obtained the following $$y_1 = \frac{x^3}{3} $$ then trying to evaluate the second approximation it becomes $$y_2 = 0 + \int \frac{x^2}{\frac{x^6}{9}+1}$$ and that how i came about evaluating this question

Comment: The solution i came across was of the following form $$y = \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{-x^9}{81}$$ but im not sure how they arrived at that solution @Jose Carlos Santos

Answer (score 3):

If you do the substitution $x^3=y$ and $3x^2\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy$, your primitive becomes$$3\int\frac{\mathrm dy}{y^2+9}=\arctan\left(\frac y3\right).$$So,$$\int\frac{9x^2}{x^6+9}\,\mathrm dx=\arctan\left(\frac{x^3}3\right).$$